# ember-cli: moduleFor fails with "Attempting to register an unknown factory" error

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli, ember-qunit

I cannot get `moduleFor` to work in a fresh build using ember-cli version 0.1.5.

When using the [documentation's example code](http://www.ember-cli.com/#moduleforfullname-description-callbacks-delegate) for `moduleFor` (and no other changes to the app), I get the following error after running `ember test`:

```
TypeError: Attempting to register an unknown factory: `route:index`
    at Object.Container.register (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:14473:17)
    at isolatedContainer (http://localhost:4200/assets/test-support.js:24:19)
    at Object._callbacks.setup (http://localhost:4200/assets/test-support.js:150:23)
    at Object.Test.setup (http://localhost:4200/assets/test-support.js:1063:31)
    at http://localhost:4200/assets/test-support.js:1168:10
    at process (http://localhost:4200/assets/test-support.js:887:24)
    at http://localhost:4200/assets/test-support.js:476:5
```

Since I haven't made any changes to the app aside from adding the sample `moduleFor` example at /tests/unit/index-test.js, this seems like it may be an ember-cli bug?  For reference, below is the code for the `moduleFor` example:

```
// my-app/tests/unit/index-test.js
import { test, moduleFor } from 'ember-qunit';

moduleFor('route:index', "Unit - IndexRoute", {
  setup: function () {},
  teardown: function () {}
});

test("it exists", function(){
  ok(this.subject());
});
```

Comment: Does the route exist?

Comment: Yes, I believe the route exists.  The Index Route is one of the automatically created routes (from  http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/defining-your-routes/#toc_initial-routes).

Comment: Yeah, but I wonder if it’s somehow different when trying to instantiate one of the auto-generated routes for testing. Does the error go away if you add a route at `app/routes/index.js`? If you don’t have a route there, what are you wanting to test?

Answer (score 3):

It seems like the route is auto-generated when it is routed to. But when running a unit test with `moduleFor()` like you are doing, there won't be an `IndexRoute` unless you explicitly declare one. If you want an `IndexRoute` you can test, you'll need to manually define it:

```
import Ember from 'ember'

IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend();

export default IndexRoute
```

If you really just want to rely on the auto-generated one, there's no reason to unit test it because there is no additional functionality to test.

I think if you turn on `LOG_ACTIVE_GENERATION` then you can see when things get generated.

If you do want to test the auto-generated one, do it in the context of an acceptance test, when you can use the router to route there.

My guess is it gets generated [here](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/ad972802517199cb602b585637b7a90fb6ed69c9/packages/ember-routing/lib/system/router.js#L380).